# AWS Storage Gateway and vSANs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, vmware, aws-storage-gateway

I'm learning about AWS Storage Gateway appliances, and I can't seem to find the answer to my question, it may be my lack of storage appliance knowledge or I'm not looking in the right place, but hope folks here can help or point me to some documentation.

I'm trying to use an AWS storage gateway appliance to back up/archive data from a particular application on an On-Prem Microsoft server to an Amazon s3 bucket. However, there is a requirement for the storage gateway to be compatible with vSANS storage since the site is a VMWare shop. I'm not super familiar with the VMWare suite, but I see in AWS I can configure a VMWare ESXi virtual machine by download the OVF template and deploying, is that all I need to set up the file share? How does the storage type being vSANs impact this approach? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storage appliance creates a file share, NFS or SMB, when using 3s storage. Your application or backup application would put the data there. vSAN won't effect anything since this would all be happening inside the VMs. It doesn't involve the underlaying storage outside the VMs, so the storage system backing the datastore doesn't come into play.

Yes, the OVF is about all you need other than a virtual network and IP for the appliance that can connect with AWS. Also a PC with a browser that can connect to both AWS and the internal ip assigned to the appliance for getting the appliance setup to your AWS. All of the instructions are baked in once you click create gateway from the AWS console.